# passing search result to another page/component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I want to search through my data and then after the search is completed I want to show the result in a new page;
this is my search page I wanna show the result in another page/component called result:

- the result will show only with secound click/enter!

  ```
    function SearchBar() {
      const [allData,setAllData] = useState([]);
      const [filteredData,setFilteredData] = useState(allData);
      const [searchTerm , setSearchTerm] = useState('')


     const dispatch = useDispatch()
     const searchItems = useSelector((state) => state.searchItems)       
     const { loading, filtered} = searchItems;         
     const getJobs=()=>{
         dispatch(SEARCHAction());
         setFilteredData(filtered)
        }

      const handleSearch = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault();
         getJobs();

    }
  return (      
      <form>
          <div>           
              <input 
                    onChange={e=>setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}                                                                              
                    id="search-input"
                    type="text" 
                    className="form-control job-field lg:col-span-9 h-12 px-3 outline-none" 
                    placeholder="job title, keywords or company name"
                    />

                 <button
                       type="submit"
                       onSubmit={handleSearch}                                    
                       className="btn search-btn border-0 lg:col-span-3">
                       <i className="fa fa-search mx-1"></i>
                 </button> 
            </div>
    </form>
   </div>
    )
   }
  ```

Comment: do you want to send the search keyword to another page? is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to show the results of search in another page. actully I want to redirect user to that page and show him the result on that page

Comment: you can send the search keyword as search query like `/results?keyword=value` then in that result page you can use useEffect and get the query params from there and display the results

Comment: In order to redirect you need to use react router.

Comment: thanks can you show me an example code?

Comment: You can also use the conditional rendering within the same page .

Comment: @fatemehzamanipour You can also keep the search results in a parent component that shres the results with the component that you wan to display them

Comment: With each search, put data in `sessionStorage` (or localStorage if you prefer) then simply change the route, and in the Component you want to show result, get the data from browser storage

Answer (score 3):

**What is happening:**

`filtered` is only updated when react rerenders. That means when you first press the button, it dispatches. But the `filtered` variable, that you push to the state, still has the old value.

**What you want to do**:

Have an extra page, as Sachin suggested: `/results?keyword=value`. Redirect to that page in the `getJobs` method. In the new page, read the value from the url and filter there.